# In HIVE SQL, a table refreshes every day. How can I retrieve data in a past date?

Tags: sql, hive

The table digital_fans has two columns, blogger_id and fans_volumn. It refreshes everyday.

I'd like to retrieve fans_volumn in the last month to check who has the highest incremental in fans_volumn.

Specifically it should be (fans_volumn data in 2021.07.31) - (fans_volumn data in 2021.07.01) for each blogger_id.

I'm not sure how to do that in HIVE SQL. Appreciate your help guys

Comment: "he table digital_fans has two columns, blogger_id and fans_volumn" -- where is the date column?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: hi ricky, it will good to have minimal reproducible example to help others better respond your question. So for this question, could produce some fake data maybe just two table's schema, fake data. and phrase your question bit more in detail.